# Issues with a Node.js implementation of AES256 CBC

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cbc-mode

Let me start off by saying I am very new to cryptography. I'm trying to implement [Cipher Block Chaining Mode](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_Block_Chaining_Mode) in Node.js.

My problem is that after an encryption without a decryption it stops working for one decryption function call. Here's my code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var encryptionMethod = 'aes-256-cbc';
var vector = new Buffer([0xF1, 0x4C, 0xB6, 0xBD, 0x82, 0x93, 0x3C, 0x97, 0x6A, 0x4B, 0x4A, 0xD2, 0xAD, 0xD5, 0xA8, 0x6D]);
var key = new Buffer([59, 92, 128, 239, 136, 26, 19, 26, 226, 234, 53, 71, 157, 113, 209, 96, 111, 83, 167, 123, 217, 107, 124, 31, 238, 176, 58, 110, 161, 82, 81, 69]);

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(encryptionMethod, key, vector);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(encryptionMethod, key, vector);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);

var encrypt = function(array) {
  return cipher.update(new Buffer(array));
};

var decrypt = function(buffer) {
  return decipher.update(buffer);
};


var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  data.push(i);
}


// no problem here (probably because the vector updates itself?)
console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));  // <Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f>
console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));  // <Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f>
console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));  // <Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f>

// after one encryption without a decryption it stops working.
console.log((encrypt(data)));

// why can't this be decrypted correctly? The last 16 entries are correct.
console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));  // <Buffer e2 df 50 63 c7 eb 06 4c 28 19 6d 04 41 bd c0 db 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f>

// expected result
console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));  // <Buffer 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f>
```

Please see the comments above the `console.log` calls for more information. How can I make sure that the `decrypt` function works all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: This is expected behavior.**

You're using the [Cipher-Block Chaining (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) mode. Where the encryption and decryption one block (16 byte) depends on the *previous* block. A block cipher is a pseudo-random permutation which means that it will always encrypt or decrypt anything as long as you give it 16 bytes of data.

With the code `console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));` you're encrypting two blocks and give them to the decryption. The last ciphertext block that was processed is remembered for the next `update` or `final` call.

Now, when you call `console.log((encrypt(data)));`, you're not passing the ciphertext to the decryption function which doesn't know the intermediate ciphertext block for the next `console.log(decrypt(encrypt(data)));`.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

> The last 16 entries are correct.

That's because CBC is not an error-propagating mode. You've encrypting two blocks at the same time. Since the second ciphertext block of the `decrypt` is intact, it will decrypt correctly.